# Play Framework - Unit testing Comet

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Comet to send information back and fwd in the browser.
Does anyone know of a way that I can write unit/automated tests for my javascript/comet server?
I want to be able to just pass the comet string and then write a unit test for the javascript.